# Derivation of variance of fitted polynomial regression

Tags: regression, variance

I am working through the ISLR book on Statistical Learning. At the bottom of page 207 in the section on polynomial regression, there is a footnote that claims:

If $\hat{C}$ is the $5\times 5$ covariance matrix of the $\hat{\beta_j}$, and if $l_0^T=(1, x_0, x_0^2, x_0^3, x_0^4)$, then $\text{Var}[\hat{f}(x_0)]=l_0^T\hat{C}l_0$. I am searching online for justification/proof of this footnote. Can anyone provide a reference to a more detailed derivation of this fact or provide a derivation here or some intuition if it is relatively straightforward?

NOTE: The above excerpt references a polynomial regression model involving terms up to degree $4$, where $x_0$ is taken to be a fixed value from the set of real numbers.